# Need a WIFI device to emulate USB storage

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, usb-storage

I have a TV satellite receiver that has a USB port to connect an external HDD to it.
In another room, I've got an ESXi server with plenty storage in RAID and stuff.
I want to have the TV receiver write to that storage, one way or another.
I'm thinking a WIFI USB dongle that simulates a storage device would cut it.

I've seen some older questions around here on the subject but I'd like to see something fresh. The devices mentioned have pretty ... shy performances, or are windows only or support only specific media formats and that sort of trouble.
I need something generic, accepting any file read/write, that behaves well and has decent reviews (just in case I will have occasional other uses for it, specifically having in mind file transfers which I currently do using a usb stick).

Thanks.

later edit:
due to being marked as duplicate, but it's really not. 
First of all, the referred has no accepted answer. And I as well cannot accept any of the 2 answers, because:
- ium drive, apparently, cannot be bought. I cannot find any place to buy it from (new).
- the IGRS linksee has bad reviews and very bad features. Size limitations are awful, to say the least. It is unusable for media recording. But I already mentioned these, at a broad level. Not to mention that it's OOS.

To sum it: old question (2010), old answers, old products, bad/weak features, bad reviews, out of stock.

I need something that is usable, has a minimum acceptable feature set considering my use-case scenario described (storage size upper limit at the TB level, file size upper limit 8GB+, read-write, plus working in my setup as explained).

And of course, something I can actually buy "today", not 3 years ago.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anyway to extend the server's storage.    The receiver unlikely even understands being hooked up to a NAS.

Comment: What you want to do probably would not work.  A USB drive connected to your TV satellite receiver would be mounted and under exclusive control of the receiver.  If instead, that port was modified to actually connect to a shared network server, then the receiver would need to be modified so that it was aware that it was dealing with a shared resource, instead of storage that it had exclusive and full control.

Comment: @Ramhound 
there is no need to extend the NAS in any way. There will be a virtual machine with a dedicated partition for this kind of data.

Comment: @sawdust Receiver writes and reads, 3rd party accesses will be rare and done manually by myself so chances for concurrent access of a file will be basically 0. There is no need for the receiver to be aware of anything special, just to see it as a usb storage device.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect device for you is called a "Patriot Gauntlet". Its a Wi-Fi storage device/hard drive. Works great. Easy interface to get it set up and once you do all you have to do is turn it on and stick it in your back pack and you have a portable wireless hard drive. Here is the link to their website if you are interested. It supports iOS, and Android as well.

http://www.patriotmemory.com/product/detail.jsp?prodline=6&catid=43&prodgroupid=237&id=1274&type=19

Comment: The problem is he has a large server to store it on. he wants the data stored on that server not on some other external device.

Comment: indeed, not "portable storage" but "remote storage", if that makes any better sense.